# Passing variables between functions in a class

Tags: python, oop, nlp, nltk

Trying to split up and tokenize a poem (or haiku in this case), which is more of a way to teach myself how to use nltk and classes than anything else.  When I run the code below, I get a `Name Error: name 'psplit' is not defined` even though (my thinking is) that it's defined when I return it from the split function.  Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong under the hood here?

```
import nltk

poem = "In the cicada's cry\nNo sign can foretell\nHow soon it must die"

class Intro():
    def __init__(self, poem):
        self.__poem = poem

    def split(self):
        psplit = (poem.split('\n'))
        psplit = str(psplit)
        return psplit

    def tokenizer(self):
        t = nltk.tokenize(psplit)
        return t

i = Intro(poem)
print(i.split())
print(i.tokenizer())
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect `tokenizer` to know what `psplit` is?

Comment: via being defined in the split function.  Is that 'definition' lost when I call `tokenizer` as a separate instantiation of the Intro class?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. The reference count of the value returned by `i.split()` drops down to zero after the first `print` function executes, so it becomes inaccessible.

Comment: For the future_ you'd want to check that the Python code in your questions is indented properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

In the `split` method you have to use `self.__poem` to access the the poem attribute of your class - as you did in the constructor.

The `psplit` variable in the `split` method is only a local variable so you can just use it in this method and nowhere else. If you want to make the variable available in the `tokenize` method you have to either pass it as an argument or store it as an additional attribute:

```
...
def tokenizer(self, psplit):
    t = nltk.tokenize(psplit)
    return t
...

psplit = i.split()
print(i.tokenizer(psplit))
```

Or:

```
def __init__(self, poem):
   ...
   self._psplit = None

...
def split(self):
    self._psplit = (poem.split('\n'))
    self._psplit = str(psplit)

def tokenizer(self):
    t = nltk.tokenize(self._psplit)
    return t

...
i.split()
print(i.tokenizer())
```

In addition make sure your indentation is correct.